# How to login first time in the login panel

Tags: aegir

I have finally managed to install aegir on a vps.
I have also set the dns of my domain and I can i can finally see my login panel.
The problem is that I don’t have username and password.
The documentation says I should have a temporary link to set the password but I can’t find that temporary link.
I tried to reset the password but obviously I can’t receive any mail because I have never done any login so far.
There is any file that I can check to find username and password please?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always generate another temporary login link.  This recipe will log you into the VM, switch you to the Aegir user, and then generate the link.

1. `ssh aegir.example.com`
2. `sudo -sHu aegir`
3. `drush @hostmaster user-login`

The output will be a URL, which you can open in your browser.

Comment: Thank you so much, many many thanks   it works perfectly